# gem install ignores gems which version number has letters

Tags: ruby, rubygems

In current directory, I have 2 built gems:
hello_gem-0.1.0.gem
hello_gem-0.1.1b.gem

These files are build with command

> gem build hello_gem.gemspec

when I run

> gem install --explain hello_gem

it prints

Gems to install:
  hello_gem-0.1.0

Why hello_gem-0.1.1b.gem is ignored?
If letters in version number are not supported, why build procedure allows them?

Sources are at https://github.com/rfqu/hello_gem

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a typo in the question:

```
▶ Gem::Version.new('0.1.0') > Gem::Version.new('0.1.1b')
#⇒ false
▶ Gem::Version.new('0.1.0') > Gem::Version.new('0.1.0b')
#⇒ true
```

`gem install` treats `0.1.0b` as being “less” than `0.1.0`, but `0.1.1b` is by any mean greater than `0.1.0`. Anyway, you always can install the explicit version with:

```
gem install hello_gem -v '0.1.1b'
```

or, even more explicitly:

```
gem install --local ./hello_gem-0.1.1b.gem
```

Since the repo you posted link to is empty, I am unable to be more precise.

Comment: thanks mudasobwa. 1) There is no typo in the question - I intentionally set version with letter greater than pure digit version. 2) "gem install hello_gem -v '0.1.1b'" yields "ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'hello_gem' (= 0.1.1b) in any repository". 3) "gem install --local ./hello_gem-0.1.1b.gem" installs gem "hello_gem-0.1.1b" in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/ but not in /usr/local/bin. 4) repo is updated.

Comment: You do not want to install gems into `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Some gems install in `/usr/local/bin`, e.g `gem install sass` instantiates `/usr/local/bin/sass`. Wonder which gems, exactly.

Comment: Those, having the respective rule in `gemspec`, obviously.